# Does changing ASP.NET to 4.0 will run the virtual directory with CLR 4?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0, iis-6, clr

We are planning to use .NET 4 with one of our webservices as it has better handling of ThreadPool.

This got me thinking, if I change the ASP.NET version that virtual directory runs under to 4.0, I dont even have to recompile my libraries with .NET 4 because IIS will spawn new w3process with .NET CLR 4 and all my libraries will be loaded in that.

That means it will use new ThreadPool with my .NET 2 libraries. Something doesnt sounds quite right?

Comment: Why do you think it is strange loading .NET 2.0 libraries strange?

Comment: It is strange in a way, that I dont have recompile my webservice against .Net4 as it will use .NET 4 CLR to run it. That means I get the benefit of .NET 4 by just changing the ASP.NET version. Is that right?

Comment: I still don't understand the reason you think that is strange.  The .NET 4.0 is designed to load .NET 2.0 assemblies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Something doesnt sounds quote right?

No, it is right. When you configure the virtual directory to use ASP.NET 4 the application will run using the CLR 4.0 even if all assemblies have been compiled against .NET 2.0.

---

UPDATE:

To verify this you could create the following `Test.aspx` page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Threading" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <%= typeof(ThreadPool).Assembly.FullName %>
</body>
</html>
```

Now compile the ASP.NET application to target .NET 2.0 and host this into a virtual directory in IIS 6.0 that's configured to use the ASP.NET 4.0 version. When you navigate to the `Test.aspx` the following output is generated:

```
mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
```

Then swap the virtual directory ASP.NET version back to 2.0 and the following is generated:

```
mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
```

So as we can see by only changing the target framework version in the virtual directory we are able to run the application in the CLR 4.0.

Comment: yeah, does that mean that I get quick win of using new ThreadPool in .NET 4 without recompiling my .NET 2 libraries ?